# I am adding admobs to my android application having this error

Tags: android, admob

Can you help me understand why I am getting this error? I am running this on emulator on proxy network but proxy is set in emulator

```
 04-11 11:10:57.845: I/dalvikvm(1441): Total arena pages for JIT: 15
 04-11 11:10:57.845: I/dalvikvm(1441): Total arena pages for JIT: 16
 04-11 11:10:57.845: I/dalvikvm(1441): Total arena pages for JIT: 17
 04-11 11:10:57.993: D/dalvikvm(1441): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 667K, 14% free 4908K/5696K, paused 45ms, total 64ms
 04-11 11:10:58.033: I/dalvikvm-heap(1441): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.980MB for 1127536-byte allocation
 04-11 11:10:58.143: D/dalvikvm(1441): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 12% free 6008K/6800K, paused 18ms+4ms, total 111ms
 04-11 11:10:59.063: E/ActivityThread(1441): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
  04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'Thread-117'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
   04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:1876)
    04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):  at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:1859)
   04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:1916)
   04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3237)
  04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3281)
   04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
   04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
    04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:504)
   04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:481)
   04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:461)
   04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:450)
   04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:440)
   04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at com.google.ads.internal.AdWebView.<init>(SourceFile:69)
  04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at com.google.ads.internal.c.<init>(SourceFile:595)
  04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at com.google.ads.l.<init>(SourceFile:46)
  04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at com.google.ads.internal.d.a(SourceFile:601)
  04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at com.google.ads.AdView.loadAd(SourceFile:575)
  04-11 11:10:59.093: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at com.rms.remotedesktop1.Home$1.run(Home.java:40)
  04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'Thread-117'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
   04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at  android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:1876)
04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):  at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:1870)
  04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:1863)
  04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:1916)
      04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3237)
    04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3281)
  04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
 04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):     at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
 04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:504)
 04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:481)
  04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:461)
 04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:450)
 04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:440)
  04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at com.google.ads.internal.AdWebView.<init>(SourceFile:69)
  04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at com.google.ads.internal.c.<init>(SourceFile:595)
  04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at com.google.ads.l.<init>(SourceFile:46)
  04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at com.google.ads.internal.d.a(SourceFile:601)
   04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at com.google.ads.AdView.loadAd(SourceFile:575)
   04-11 11:10:59.173: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at com.rms.remotedesktop1.Home$1.run(Home.java:40)
   04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'Thread-117'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
   04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:1876)
  04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:1859)
   04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:1916)
    04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3638)
  04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
    04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):  at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
      04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:504)
       04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:481)
         04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:461)
      04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:450)
     04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:440)
     04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):     at com.google.ads.internal.AdWebView.<init>(SourceFile:69)
     04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):     at com.google.ads.internal.c.<init>(SourceFile:595)
     04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):     at com.google.ads.l.<init>(SourceFile:46)
      04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at com.google.ads.internal.d.a(SourceFile:601)
       04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at com.google.ads.AdView.loadAd(SourceFile:575)
      04-11 11:10:59.234: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at com.rms.remotedesktop1.Home$1.run(Home.java:40)
        04-11 11:10:59.273: W/webview_proxy(1441): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'Thread-117'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
        04-11 11:10:59.273: W/webview_proxy(1441):  at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:1876)
         04-11 11:10:59.273: W/webview_proxy(1441):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:508)
       04-11 11:10:59.273: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:481)
          04-11 11:10:59.273: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:461)
          04-11 11:10:59.273: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:450)
        04-11 11:10:59.273: W/webview_proxy(1441):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:440)
04-11 11:10:59.273: W/webview_proxy(1441):  at com.google.ads.internal.AdWebView.<init>(SourceFile:69)
04-11 11:10:59.273: W/webview_proxy(1441):  at com.google.ads.internal.c.<init>(SourceFile:595)

  04-11 11:10:59.473: W/webview_proxy(1441):    at com.rms.remotedesktop1.Home$1.run(Home.java:40)
  04-11 11:10:59.503: W/webview_proxy(1441): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'Thread-117'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
   04-11 11:10:59.503: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:1876)
    04-11 11:10:59.503: W/webview_proxy(1441):  at android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient(WebView.java:1449) 
       04-11 11:10:59.503: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at com.google.ads.internal.c.<init>(SourceFile:596)
     04-11 11:10:59.503: W/webview_proxy(1441):     at com.google.ads.l.<init>(SourceFile:46)
     04-11 11:10:59.503: W/webview_proxy(1441):     at com.google.ads.internal.d.a(SourceFile:601)
           04-11 11:10:59.503: W/webview_proxy(1441):   at com.google.ads.AdView.loadAd(SourceFile:575)
        04-11 11:10:59.503: W/webview_proxy(1441):  at com.rms.remotedesktop1.Home$1.run(Home.java:40)
      04-11 11:10:59.833: I/Ads(1441): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"4756462099350048181","seq_num":"1","slotname":"a1515bd9e7d17a7","u_w":360,"msid":"com.rms.remotedesktop1","cap":"m,a","adtest":"on","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.3.1","bas_off":0,"net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.com.rms.remotedesktop1","hl":"en","gnt":3,"carrier":"310260","u_audio":4,"u_sd":2,"simulator":1,"ms":"LtRWUhLlWUASTYe1oOnwxpVjmZnlRqOPLlW88n3MZLyUIZoTiH6abFi7BH7nGouLlV33IKIAkDbG1KGMrOiZyCWF0-5XPwlhEfsjYddXZIeOob_q44FdcJqzmxhuYSp_n0I3ZrgvBpsfqpPVKrjEB88E8jJqZ5x5i0fmTi_LD0gzvPRkxD32br4c3ew4b9Ze2SqkFkGWWBWACkqm43ObDu1jzufW9TBLyvTxdw8kozJ_9EgSKWNC3OAaFUiT_xOEU_C7sqgMmQUZ_IQVrZaJrbT7UqtIWrCzxxliBS9lRBkz_EF74SqVBAHD6t84RBkaR8CuxNAClGgMskAuW3jAog","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":592,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0});</script></head><body></body></html>
       04-11 11:11:02.214: W/chromium(1441): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/backend_impl.cc:1835: [0411/111101:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1835)] Destroying invalid entry.
        04-11 11:11:59.596: I/Ads(1441): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL.
       04-11 11:1159.602: I/Ads(1441): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
         04-11 11:12:59.702: I/Ads(1441): Refreshing ad.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adview.loadAd(new AdRequest())` needs to be called on the UI thread. It looks like you're trying to instantiate AdMob on a background thread.

Comment: I have wriiten this code in onCreate() method:
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adLayout);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

I am also getting same warning.